# CMIS connection issue

Tags: alfresco, cmis

cannot tell if this issue is the same as some others posted. ours simply throws a msg, but it appears CMIS connection related - our application uses CMIS/Alfresco. i am not very familiar, but we have a server related to it. *not sure* if a power outage is related to the fact that we this error[pwr outage yesterday, then mysteriously this error was later noticed]. we normally post information on the web page that is populated by our sql data[a table field populates a textarea/text editor] - instead we get the error above: "CMIS connection issue". that verbiage comes from a file that instantiates connection with CMIS, here is the related code:

```
//Check cmis service connect or not
try{
$client = new CMISService($repo_url, $repo_username, $repo_password);
}catch (Exception $ec) {
    echo "CMIS connection issue";
    echo "<br >\n" ;
    echo $ec->getMessage() ;
    die;
}
```

the CMISService parms have not changed, and they appear to be proper values. i even tried "admin", and "root" as "repo_username" in addition to the defined username.

Ideas on what we can check?

Comment: what does $ec-getMessage() prints ? and how about checking the url with CMIS workbench. You can get some logs from the workbench too on why it is failing.

Comment: the catch code echos 6 lines: 1-CMIS connection issue, 2-HTTP Status 404 - /alfresco/service/cmis, 3-type Status report, 4-message /alfresco/service/cmis, 5-description The requested resource is not available, 6-Apache Tomcat/7.0.54. i downloaded CMIS workbench, entered the repo_url and id/pw and got this: "The CMIS Workbench could connect to the server but the provided URL is not a CMIS endpoint URL. Check your URL and proxy settings." LOG: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54 - Error report; also, The requested resource is not available.

Comment: So its self-explanatory...you are not providing the right URL...check for some url endpoints for alfresco here https://www.alfresco.com/cmis and here http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/cmis-41-endpoint.html